# How can I test if a pytest fixture raises an exception?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Use case: In a `pytest` test suite I have a `@fixture` which raises exceptions if command line options for its configuration are missing. I've written a test for this fixture using `xfail`:

```
import pytest
from <module> import <exception>

@pytest.mark.xfail(raises=<exception>)
def test_fixture_with_missing_options_raises_exception(rc_visard):
    pass
```

However the output after running the tests does not state the test as passed but "xfailed" instead:

```
============================== 1 xfailed in 0.15 seconds ========================
```

In addition to that I am not able to test if the `fixture` raises the exception for specific missing command line options.

Is there a better approach to do this? Can I mock the `pytest` command line options somehow that I do not need to call specific tests via `pytest --<commandline-option-a> <test-file-name>::<test-name>`.

Comment: Why is the exception raised in the fixture? What are you trying to do? If you are testing whether a function raises an exception, you should call it in the test itself, inside a `with pytest.raises(MyError)` block.

Comment: It is no dublicate because in that question no fixture raise an exception.

Comment: I want to ensure that for a fixture no "command line options for its configuration are missing".

Comment: Oh, so you want to write a test for the fixture itself?

Comment: Yes. It turned out that e.g. complex command line options are error prone w.r.t. usability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### initial setup

Suppose you have a simplified project with `conftest.py` containing the following code:

```python
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--foo', action='store', dest='foo', default='bar',
                     help='--foo should be always bar!')

@pytest.fixture
def foo(request):
    fooval = request.config.getoption('foo')
    if fooval != 'bar':
        raise ValueError('expected foo to be "bar"; "{}" provided'.format(fooval))
```

It adds a new command line arg `--foo` and a fixture `foo` returning the passed arg, or `bar` if not specified. If anything else besides `bar` passed via `--foo`, the fixture raises a `ValueError`.

You use the fixture as usual, for example

```python
def test_something(foo):
    assert foo == 'bar'
```

Now let's test that fixture.

#### preparations

In this example, we need to do some simple refactoring first. Move the fixture and related code to some file called something else than `conftest.py`, for example, `my_plugin.py`:

```python
# my_plugin.py

import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--foo', action='store', dest='foo', default='bar',
                     help='--foo should be always bar!')

@pytest.fixture
def foo(request):
    fooval = request.config.getoption('foo')
    if fooval != 'bar':
        raise ValueError('expected foo to be "bar"; "{}" provided'.format(fooval))
```

In `conftest.py`, ensure the new plugin is loaded:

```python
# conftest.py

pytest_plugins = ['my_plugin']
```

Run the existing test suite to ensure we didn't break anything, all tests should still pass.

#### activate `pytester`

`pytest` provides an extra plugin for writing plugin tests, called `pytester`. It is not activated by default, so you should do that manually. In `conftest.py`, extend the plugins list with `pytester`:

```python
# conftest.py

pytest_plugins = ['my_plugin', 'pytester']
```

#### writing the tests

Once `pytester` is active, you get a new fixture available called `testdir`. It can generate and run `pytest` test suites from code. Here's what our first test will look like:

```python
# test_foo_fixture.py

def test_all_ok(testdir):

    testdata = '''
               def test_sample(foo):
                   assert True
               '''

    testconftest = '''
                   pytest_plugins = ['my_plugin']
                   '''

    testdir.makeconftest(testconftest)
    testdir.makepyfile(testdata)
    result = testdir.runpytest()
    result.assert_outcomes(passed=1)
```

It should be pretty obvious what happens here: we provide the tests code as string and `testdir` will generate a `pytest` project from it in some temporary directory. To ensure our `foo` fixture is available in the generated test project, we pass it in the generated `conftest` same way as we do in the real one. `testdir.runpytest()` starts the test run, producing a result that we can inspect.

Let's add another test that checks whether `foo` will raise a `ValueError`:

```python
def test_foo_valueerror_raised(testdir):
    testdata = '''
               def test_sample(foo):
                   assert True
               '''

    testconftest = '''
                   pytest_plugins = ['my_plugin']
                   '''

    testdir.makeconftest(testconftest)
    testdir.makepyfile(testdata)
    result = testdir.runpytest('--foo', 'baz')                                                                                                                                
    result.assert_outcomes(errors=1)
    result.stdout.fnmatch_lines([
        '*ValueError: expected foo to be "bar"; "baz" provided'
    ])
```

Here we execute the generated tests with `--foo baz` and verify afterwards if one test ended with an error and the error output contains the expected error message.

Comment: Thx a lot. As soon as I tried it out I'll accept the answer.