# Testing a pytest fixture

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

I'm creating a library of our commonly used custom pytest fixtures. Some of them are complex enough that I'd like to add some tests for them.

However, once a function has been decorated with `@pytest.fixture`, it cannot be called directly anymore:

```py
import pytest 

@pytest.fixture 
def foo(): 
    return 1 

foo()
```

raises

```
Failed: Fixture "foo" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.
See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html for more information about fixtures, and
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly about how to update your code.
```

pytest keeps the original function around in the fixture object, but I couldn't find a documented way to access it without messing with pytest's internals.

**How can I test my fixtures, especially those using `yield` to do some cleanup after a test case runs?**

Comment: Expose it yourself - name it e.g. `_foo` then write `foo = pytest.fixture(_foo)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56631622/2650249